# No type error when comparing boolean with null in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm surprise why Typescript would not report a a type error when comparing the constant `bool` with `null`:

```js
function get(): boolean {
    return Math.random() > 0.5;
}

const bool = get();
if (bool !== null) {
    console.log('bool is not null');
}
```

TypeScript Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQBQEoBciBGccANqgIZIDeAUInYgE7ogNICyZUAFgHQMUATOAFtsiAHyIADDwCsAbmoBfatQgIAzlAJFiiALwp02RTGCIMhEogCE+w2BDFiWRDXqJ1YDSVQ9icMgYAORWejAaiGBw2o7OwViKKkA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a TypeScript error to use equality comparison, even if the comparison doesn't make sense since it'll always be true or false.

But if you use TSLint, you can generate a warning when this sort of thing is encountered with the [strict-type-predicates](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/strict-type-predicates/) rule. (It doesn't appear to be integrated [into ESLint yet](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/ROADMAP.md), unfortunately)

[image]

Comment: There is TS2367 which does exactly that - `"This condition will always return 'false' since the types ..."`. And when `null` is replaced with any string, typescript does complain in the OP's example.

Comment: I did test my example on the TypeScript Playground before asking here and did not get any error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQBQEoBciBGccANqgIZIDeAUInYgE7ogNICyZUAFgHQMUATOAFtsiAHyIADDwCsAbmoBfatQgIAzlAJFiiALwp02RTGCIMhEogCE+w2BDFiWRDXqJ1YDSVQ9icMgYAORWejAaiGBw2o7OwViKKkA